# ERROR REPORT Generic server <0.35.0> terminating Last message in was {req_timeout,#Ref<0.0.0.60>}

Tags: erlang, riak, erlang-shell, erlang-ports

I am going through the riak-erlang-client https://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client. As i am following the steps, i am facing error at storing the data.

I did the following:

```
2> {ok,Pid} = riakc_pb_socket:start_link("127.0.0.1",8087).
{ok,<0.35.0>}
3> 
3> 
3> riakc_pb_socket:ping(Pid).
pong
4> Val = 1.                                         
1
7> Obj = riakc_obj:new(<<"Bucket">>,<<"one">>,Val). 
{riakc_obj,<<"Bucket">>,<<"one">>,undefined,[],undefined,1}
```

everything was working here as per the documents, but when i am trying to store the data with the following command.

```
 8> riakc_pb_socket:put(Pid,Obj).
```

After this command i am getting the following error,

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 13-May-2014::18:15:46 ===
** Generic server <0.35.0> terminating 
** Last message in was {req_timeout,#Ref<0.0.0.60>}
** When Server state == {state,"127.0.0.1",8087,false,false,undefined,false,
                           gen_tcp,undefined,
                           {[],[]},
                           1,[],infinity,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                           undefined,[],100}
** Reason for termination == 
** disconnected
** exception exit: disconnected
```

where i am doing wrong, please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that your TCP request timed out for some reason.  Is there anything in Riak's `error.log` or `console.log` files that could tell you why?

Can you test to see if your Riak node is running by going to `http:127.0.0.1:8098/ping` in a browser?

If it's up and running you can try your test again by either clearing your currently bound variables with `f().` (or opening a new Erlang REPL), and retrying the commands.

Comment: I have done it but again it is showing the same thing, the error in the logs was like the following:    2014-05-13 20:29:05.563 [error] emulator Error in process <0.7602.0> on node 'riak@127.0.0.1' with exit value: {emfile,[{erlang,open_port,[{spawn,"/home/intel/Downloads/riak-1.4.8/rel/riak/bin/../lib/os_mon-2.2.7/priv/bin/cpu_sup"},[stream]]},{cpu_sup,start_portprogram,0},{cpu_sup,port_server_init,1}]}

Comment: Ahh you're running into the `EMFILE` error, you'll need to increase your open files limit on your operating system as outlined in the docs: http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Linux.

Comment: @gopi Did you adjust your `ulimit` settings and get around this problem?

Comment: ya when i go for ulimit it was giving unlimited to, even i again set ulimit as 4096

Comment: 2014-05-16 20:53:10.717 [info] <0.398.0>@riak_kv_entropy_manager:perhaps_log_throttle_change:826 Changing AAE throttle from undefined -> 0 msec/key, based on maximum vnode mailbox size 0 from 'dev3@127.0.0.1'

Comment: What Operating System are you running @gopi?

Comment: I am using Centos @Alex Moore

Comment: @gopi You will probably have to change it using the `/etc/security/limits.conf` method.  See the [Linux / limits.conf](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Linux) section on how to do it.